# batch split word by Typed keyboard

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch whit this code

```
set /p carga=

for /F "tokens=1-2" %%a in (%carga%) do (
Zero
    if "%%a"=="c" (sqlcmd -d bd_ofb -Q "exec dbo.SP_OFB_INF_PSN @VALOR = 1, @FECHA=''" -S (local^) -o OFB_INF_PSN_2.tx)

    if "%%a"=="f" (sqlcmd -d bd_ofb -Q "exec dbo.SP_OFB_INF_PSN @VALOR = 2, @FECHA='%%b'" -S (local^) -o OFB_INF_PSN_2.txt)
)
```

but i have a error

> the system cannot find the file c

and if a write the f 2016/10/17 the error is

> the system cannot find the file f

thanks

Comment: It would be nice if you told us what the script should do, my clairvoyant skills are quite poor...

Answer (score 1):

```
for /F "tokens=1-2" %%a in ("%carga%") do (
```

If the string is quoted, `for/f` parses it.

If it's unquoted, `for/f` assumes it's a filename.

Comment: for/f "tokens=1-2" %%a in (%carga%) do (
)

Comment: but the error is 'for' is not recongnized as an internal or external comand